# pygame in python 3.9.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was using pygame yesterday with my version of python 3.9 and everything worked.
Today I decided to upgrade to python 3.9.1 but it is not opening the pygame window.
It does not show me an error or nothing just does not appear.
If I use another version of python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 if it is working for me. Is it something with the version or something am I doing wrong?
PS: I'm new to programming.

```
import pygame
 
pygame.init()
 
size = [400, 500]
display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
 
pygame.display.set_caption("test")
 
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
while not done:
 
    for evento in pygame.event.get(): 
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

i am using sublime text3:
[image]

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? (Ideally, you should be.) If not, how did you install Python? How did you upgrade it? How did you install PyGame?

Comment: If something works, you shouldn't need to upgrade minor/patch versions

Comment: @Rabbid76 It doesn't look like Windows (Bash), based on the UI; it is most likely a Linux distro or MacOS (Unix).

Comment: i am using winndow 10. pygame version is 2.0.1. I am not using virtual environment. I had installed with pip when I had version 3.9.0. Since I'm new, I don't really understand much about using the virtual environment. update python 3.9.0 to 3.9.1 by downloading it from the official website and I gave it update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you written `pygame.evento.get`
you should type `pygame.event.get`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information about the operating system and what version of PyGame want to use.

See [this issue about Python 3.9 support](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2145) where you can find more information and answers from the community and I think you will find the solution to this question:

*I was able to install PyGame 2.0 from the source code with Python 3.9.1. on Fedora Linux distro.*

**... based on the author's comment on this question and subsequent additions:**

**the latest functional versions are Python 3.9.0 and PyGame 2.0**

Comment: i am using winndow 10. pygame version is 2.0.1. I am not using virtual environment. I had installed with pip when I had version 3.9.0. Since I'm new, I don't really understand much about using the virtual environment.  update python 3.9.0 to 3.9.1 by downloading it from the official website and I gave it update.